# wordpressのデザインテンプレートのcssを取得して、他のwebアプリケーションに組み込むことは法的や、実装上、可能でしょうか？

Tags: php, css, wordpress

## 背景

wordpressのテンプレートは非常に種類が多く、かつ、素晴らしいデザインのものが
無償、有償含めたくさんあるなと感じました。

また、このディレクトリ内を見ると、cssなどが入っており、こういうのを使えるのかなと思いました。
wp-content/themes/

## 理由

css等で、一からデザインしていくのが得意ではないのと、bootstrapを前提に構成していくのも限界があるため、wordpressに使われているデザインテンプレートを上手く再活用できればいいなと思いました。

## その上での質問です

1) こういうデザインテンプレートを使用しても問題ないのでしょうか？
（ケースバイケースだとは思いますが）

2) それらの判断はどこを見て決めたらいいのでしょうか？
コピーライトの有無とか、商標の話なのかなとは思いますが、よくわからず。
特に有償で購入してしまったら、こちらのもの？なので、どのように使ってもいいのかなと思いました。

3) 仮に上手くデザインテンプレートを取り出せたとして、それを例えば、PHPやRuby、Pythonなどをベースとしたwebアプリケーションに移植した時、上手くできるものなのでしょうか？

宜しくお願いします。

Answer (score 2):

結論だけ言えば**可能です**
(が、おそらく独自カスタムは必要になるかもしれません)

> 2) それらの判断はどこを見て決めたらいいのでしょうか？

ライセンスを見て判断してください

#### ライセンスについて

WordPressのテーマは**原則GPL**を継承しています。ただし、GPLの継承が必須とされるのはPHP部分のみで或るため有償テーマなどによってはCSSや画像についてはそうでない場合があるので購入時に確認ください。
GPLなどの場合、使用用途に制限は付けられないため、WordPress意外に使用することも可能です。

例えば、[公式ディレクトリ](https://ja.wordpress.org/themes)に掲載されているテーマは全て100%GPLです。

よくわからない場合は販売、頒布元などに確認してみてください。

themeforestの例
[image: Themeforestの例]

> 3) 仮に上手くデザインテンプレートを取り出せたとして、それを例えば、PHPやRuby、Pythonなどをベースとしたwebアプリケーションに移植した時、上手くできるものなのでしょうか？

これこそケースバイケースだと思いますが……

WordPressのテーマは基本的にWordPressの吐き出すクラスに合わせて制作されています。
言い換えれば、そのテーマをつかったWPサイトを用意し、そのサイトと同様のHTMLが吐き出せるようにアプリケーションを組めれば使い物になるかと思います。

テーマによってはSCSSなどのプリプロセッサを利用している元ソースが付属している場合もあるのでうまく活用出来るかもしれません。

#### 参考： WPテーマの構成

WPテーマは主に以下の要素で構成されています

- CSS (style.css など)
- テーマ用のPHP関数 (functions.phpや/inc/template-tags.php のようなファイル)
- PHPテンプレート
- JavaScript ファイル (ない場合も)
- 画像
- 翻訳ファイル (最近はテーマ外に……)

あくまでもWPテーマはWPのために作られている場合が大半なのでそこら辺は……。